# String boolean confusion

Tags: java, string, boolean, equals

I was doing a practice Computer science test and tried this question out.

```
String sam = "scary";
String ben = new String("scary");
String wil = "scary";
out.print( sam == ben );
out.print( " " + (sam == wil) );
```

From my knowledge I thought the printouts would be false false because  from what I know, strings can only be compared with .equals(). But I got it wrong. It says that the answer was false true. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: So add the [java] tag to your question next time @user2990622

Comment: String interning is the reason: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Answer (score 4):

You *can* compare strings with `==`. However, that compares string *references* rather than the character sequences.

If the two character sequences are different, `==` will always evaluate to `false`. If they are the same, `==` may return `true` or may return `false`; this depends on how the two string objects came into existence.

The reason `sam` and `wil` refer to the same object is spelled out in [JLS §3.10.5 String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> String literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method [`String.intern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).

See Example 3.10.5-1 in the JLS for a detailed illustration of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

When you create Strings without the new word the jre searches in a pool of Strings that you created before for a String that has the same content ,if it finds one then there is no need to create a new String in the memory and just refferences the new String to the one you created before. In the other hand  by using the new keyword you are forcing to create a new Object.